# Impact of Re-compute Statistics flag in SQL Server 2014 when creating an index

Tags: sql-server, database-design

When creating a new non-clustered index on a column in a table in the SQL Server, what does the Re-compute statistics flag do? is it a onetime operation that happens during the creation of the index? or does it impact data modifications? (Re-compute stats every time a data operation occurs?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flag `STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE` just disable any future automatic statistic updates. In case you have special automated procedure to update statistics that option is needed.

However, most of the time statistics auto-update works fine and better to skip `STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE` option to prevent query optimizer from picking wrong query plan based on old statistics.

Comment: So what you are saying is that this flag should be kept off in most cases?

Comment: Exactly. Unless you are in an environment when you can't afford having auto-update statistics during busy business hours.